# How to return to homepage using a dxAction dxButton?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, devextreme

there seems to be such little documentation on the [DevExtreme website](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/?version=14_1) about how to go about linking/returning to the 'Main Page' after the user has 'finished' the app (i.e. got to last page and wants to return home - and yes, i nkow in most phones there is a 'home' button in the nav bar, but i am looking to remove this!).

I have been creating a `dxButton` such as:

```
<div data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Button1' }, dxAction: '#myNextPage/'"></div>
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a way of 'returning' to the home page through this type of link?

I have already tried using `dxAction: '#home/'` - and yes, it does go to the home page - but it leave a 'Back' button at the top of the page (which obviously isn't there when you first start up the app).

I have tried other alternatives, such as `dxAction: '#/'` etc, but none seem to have worked.

has anyone found a way of doing this (seemingly) simple task?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, you could use application method `navigate` with option `{ root: true }`

```
<div data-bind="dxButton: { 
    text: 'Button1', 
    clickAction: function() { 
        app.navigate('home', { root: true }); 
    } 
}"></div>
```

More info in docs:
http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Application_Framework/HtmlApplication/Methods/?version=14_1#navigateuri_options

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to be able to use this method? 'app' nor <myProjectName>, nor anything else possibly related seems to be available?

Comment: The app is usually in root namespace e.g. `Application1.app`, so it's `<myProjectName>.app`